# How to update Mac OS X 10.9 keychain access

Tags: macos, security, password, keychain

I am using Mac OS X 10.9 and I am trying to update my keychain password. I have just changed some Facebook password so that now when I log into Facebook, the password that is put by my Mac OS X system is the older one. How can I update my keychain password ?

Answer (score 1):

Open keychain assistant, find the old entry and delete it.